# Xamarin Scroll View não funciona

Tags: xamarin.android

Coloquei um scrollview e minha LinearLayout principal dentro dele. 
Fiz isso por que quando vou digitar, alguns campos some atrás do Keyboard.

Bom, o que ocorre é que o scrollView não apresenta scroll e parte do meu formulário fica escondido atrás do teclado.. :(

O que pode estar errado?

Comment: Desculpe vou postar um trexo do código acho que fica melhor...

Comment: Poste o código aqui para lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Descobri o problema, além de usar o scroll eu tenho que colocar essa propriedade nos atributos da activity

**`WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize,`**

```
[Activity (Label = "CadastroActivity", WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar")]
```

Ai funcionou :D